# SQLAlchemy Reference Column Through Foreign Key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

If I have an `operator` table and a `user` table, and I have more than one relationship to the `user` table within `operator` where `pm` is a `relationship()` that joins on `operator.pm_id == user.id` and `sales` is a `relationship()` that joins on `operator.sales_id == user.id`, how can I reference a `username` column from within the `user` table in a select statement, similar to the following:

`stmt = select([operator, operator.pm.username.label('pm'), operator.sales.username.label('sales')])`

This obviously doesn't work, but how can I accomplish something similar?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to accomplish here. Do you want to perform a join operation? An aggregate? Could you describe in plain english the desired result of the query?

Comment: If I say select([operator]), I get the basic operator columns and 2 id's: pm_id, and sales_id. All I'd like to do is return the usernames of those 2 id's from the user table instead of the integer id's.

Instead of `operator.name ...  |   operator.pm_id   |   operator.sales_id`, return `operator.name ...  |   operator.pm(username from user table)   |   operator.sales(different username from user table) `

Answer (score 0):

The core idea is this:

```
stmt = select([operator.name, user.name])
stmt = stmt.select_from(operator.join(user, operator.pm_id==user.id))
```

You can generate joins of columns from multiple tables by using the select_from statement in this way.

The last part where you want to add

> operator.sales(different username from user table)

I still don't fully understand. But maybe you can use the scheme above to solve this too.

EDIT:

To make this explicit: You can chain this operation indefinitely, e.g.

```
stmt = stmt.select_from(table1.join(table2, table1.key==table2.key).join(table3, table2.key==table3.key))
```

etc..

Comment: This works beautifully when there's only one relationship between `operator` and `user` on `user.id`, but I get confused as to what to do when I want the `username` attribute from `user` for both the pm and sales rep at the same time.

Comment: In my edit I mentioned how to expand the scheme to multiple joins. Just apply it to your use pattern.